# React shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I am trying to add the shouldcomponentupdate lifestyle method to my code.  now it will not show the list. and keypress it wont do anything. any suggestions thanks much
  Here is my code:

```
  const list1Items = ["Eggs", "Bread", "Artisinal cheese"];
     const list2Items = ["Trains", "Planes", "Automobiles"];

  class List extends React.Component {
      state = {
        items: []
      }


      shouldComponentUpdate() {
           return JSON.stringify(nextProps.items) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.items);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
           document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
      }
      handleKeydown(event) {
          // this checks if the 1 key is pressed
          if (event.code === "Digit1") { 
                this.setState({items: list1Items}); 
          }
          // this checks if the 2 key is pressed
          else if (event.code === "Digit2") { 
              this.setState({items: list2Items}); 
          }
      }
      render() {

        console.log("List's render function");
        const list = this.state.items.map(item => (<li key={item}>{item}</li>));

        return (
          <ul>
              {list}
          </ul>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
       <List/>,
       document.getElementById("root")
    )

Thanks for helping in advance
```

Comment: Can you provide a version of your code with the `shouldComponentUpdate` method implemented?

Answer (score 0):

```
class List extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    // if you're using ImmutableJS or something like that you can do:
    return nextProps.items !== this.props.items

    // If you're using plain JavaScript you have to check based on your knowledge of the structure like:
    return !nextProps.items.every((item, index) => i.name === this.props.items[index].name)

    // Otherwise, if you don't know the structure, you need to do it the dumb way:
    return JSON.stringify(nextProps.items) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.items)
  }

  render() {
    console.log("List's render function"); // this should not happen if the exact same props are provided a second time
    const list = this.props.items.map(item => (<li key={item}>{item}</li>));

    return (
      <ul>
          {list}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would implement a shouldComponentUpdate in your React component class, however you need to structure your code a little better, by providing the dom listener in your React component and not outside of it

```
  const list1Items = ['Eggs', 'Bread', 'Artisinal cheese'];
  const list2Items = ['Trains', 'Planes', 'Automobiles'];
  class List extends React.Component {
      state = {
        items: [];
      }
      shouldComponentUpdate() {
          // write your logic here
          // compare current state and next state here
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
           document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
      }
      handleKeydown(event) {
          // this checks if the 1 key is pressed
          if (event.code === "Digit1") { 
                this.setState({items: list1Items}); 
          }
          // this checks if the 2 key is pressed
          else if (event.code === "Digit2") { 
              this.setState({items: list2Items}); 
          }
      }
      render() {
        console.log("List's render function");
        const list = this.state.items.map(item => (<li key={item}>{item}</li>));

        return (
          <ul>
              {list}
          </ul>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
       <List/>,
       document.getElementById("root")
    )
```

Comment: HI i am still getting an error.  and the list is not showing. it sais map is underfined.  Thanks for getting back to me on this.   i have attached my code

Comment: Would you show the "map" error? Seems that this line should be
   const list = this.state.items.map(item => (<li key={item}>{item}</li>));
, using state instead of props.

Comment: @Han, yes you are right. this.props.items should be this.state.items

Comment: hi thanks i updated my code. but still wont work.  now it seems like its mapping but the list does not come up on keypress thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 const list1Items = ["Eggs", "Bread", "Artisinal cheese"];
     const list2Items = ["Trains", "Planes", "Automobiles"];

  class List extends React.Component {
      state = {
        items: []
      }


      shouldComponentUpdate() {
           return JSON.stringify(nextProps.items) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.items);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
           document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeydown.bind(this));
      }
      handleKeydown(event) {
          // this checks if the 1 key is pressed
          if (event.code === "Digit1") { 
                this.setState({items: list1Items}); 
          }
          // this checks if the 2 key is pressed
          else if (event.code === "Digit2") { 
              this.setState({items: list2Items}); 
          }
      }
      render() {
        console.log("List's render function");
        const list = this.props.items.map(item => (<li key={item}>{item}</li>));

        return (
          <ul>
              {list}
          </ul>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
       <List/>,
       document.getElementById("root")
    )
```